# How to get more parameters from resolved system entity?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm working on the flight search agent using API.AI.
It bases on the pre-built Flight agent.

The agent recognizes the origin/destination location by either city name (e.g. London) or the airport code (e.g LHR).
The city is resolved to the following json:

```
{"city":"London"}
```

However, the airport code gets resolved to:

```
{"business-name":"London Heathrow Airport"}
```

The names are resolved using built-in entities (I tried `@sys.location`, `@sys.geo-city` and `@sys.airport`).
The search engine underneath recognizes both LHR and London, but it doesn't have a clue what "London Heathrow Airport" is.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.api.ai/docs/concept-entities#section-geography) the location can contain the following fields:

`{
    "country":"United States of America",
    "admin-area":"New York",
    "business-name":"Baxter Building",
    "city":"New York",
    "street-address":"42nd St",
    "zip-code":"10036"`
}

Since API.AI did recognize LHR as a London airport - is it possible to make it return more data about the location?

E.g. something like that:

`{
    "business-name":"London Heathrow Airport",
    "city":"London"`
}

Alternatively, is there a way to access the input parameter that was resolved to `"business-name"` (LHR in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the 'original' value of the parameter before it is resolved using .original, so instead of a value of `$parameter_name` try `$parameter_name.original`

Comment: Thanks. I did try that, but apparently the `$parameter_name` resolves the entire phrase (e.g. "from LHR") instead of just a word that was recognized as an airport code (LHR).

Comment: That seems odd/poorly designed for an entity supposed to represent Airports, are you sure you are highlighting the entity syntax correctly?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it wouldn't resolve the value of e.g. LHR.

Comment: You wouldn't conceptually need 'from' in 'from LHR' to resolve to an airport entity- it's entirely possible to design it without lumping the 'from' into the airport entity to be resolved, which is why this seems really odd.